# Continuous Closed Contours and their Images

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following statement true?

> If $U$ is any domain, if $f$ is any function continuous on $U$, if $\gamma$ is any closed contour such that its image, and its interior lie in $U$, then 
>   $$
> \int_γ f(z)\,dz = 0?
> $$

I can't get my head around all the different conditions, can anyone help me?

Comment: Try with any non-holomorphic function, what do you get ?

Comment: Surely if it's non holomorphic then the integral has a value?

Comment: You have to read your course, the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration) of a contour integral $\int_\gamma f(z)dz$ (and also use latex when posting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true. Take for example $f(z) = \bar z$ which is clearly continuous everywhere. On the other hand
$$
\int_{|z|=1} \bar z\,dz = \int_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{z} = 2\pi i
$$
by Cauchy's integral formula. (Of course direct parametrization works just as well.)

Comment: I don't understand how \bar{ z } = 1/z, and surely then it isn't continuous for z=0?

Comment: On $|z|=1$, $$ \bar z = \frac{\bar z \cdot z}{z} = \frac1z,$$ which is all you need for the integral. I'm not saying that $\bar z = 1/z$ for all $z$.